# Insert string into a specific line in a text file

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I have an excel sheet with strings in the rows.
I have a txt file.
I already have the specific number of lines I want to insert the strings.

but when I use "write" it deletes all and then inserts the string.

How can I insert a string into a specific line in a text file? i'll use a loop to open and close all the txt files.

the code works. just need to put the string in the txt file.
p.s the note is in Hebrew.

```
Sub SearchTextFile()


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------úçéìú øéöú ÷åã
    Dim Start, Finish, TotalTime As Date

    Start = Timer

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------áéèåì çéùåáéí åòãëåðé îñê åäúøàåú
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------äçæøú çéùåáéí åòãëåðé îñê åäúøàåú
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True


    Dim strLine1, strLine2, strSearch1, strSearch2, Mid1, Mid2 As String
    Dim i, j, z, h As Integer
    Dim x, LineCount1, LineCount2 As Long
    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    x = 2
    LineCount1 = 0
    h = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(x, 2))

        myFileCOMPANY = "L:\" & Cells(x, 2) & "\COMPANY.bat" 'áãé÷ä øàùåðéí äàí îñôø äçáøä ÷ééí áëìì

        If Not Dir(myFileCOMPANY) = "" Then 'àí ìà øé÷

           strFileName = "L:\" & Cells(x, 2) & "\COMPANY.bat" 'ðúéá - àéôä ìçôù

           strSearch1 = Cells(x, 7)  'îä ìçôù
           strSearch1 = "If Exist Dfile" & Format(strSearch1, "000") 'ùéðåé ôåøîè

           i = FreeFile

           On Error Resume Next
           Open strFileName For Input As #i

           Do While Not EOF(i)

               LineCount1 = LineCount1 + 1
               Line Input #i, strLine1

               If InStr(1, strLine1, strSearch1, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then 'äáéã÷ä òöîä äàí äè÷ñè ùîçôùéí ÷ééí áùåøä äæå

                     strSearch2 = "pz-"

                     Line Input #i, strLine2

                         For j = 1 To 4
                         If InStr(1, strLine2, strSearch2, vbBinaryCompare) + 1 > 0 Then 'äáéã÷ä òöîä äàí äè÷ñè ùîçôùéí ÷ééí áùåøä äæå

                             Cells(x, 11) = Cells(x, 2) 'îñôø çáøä
                             Cells(x, 12) = Format(Cells(x, 7), "000") 'îñôø úú
                             Cells(x, 13) = LineCount1 + j 'îñôø ùåøä
                             blnFound = True
                             Cells(x, 14) = Len(strLine2) 'àåøê ùåøä
                             Cells(x, 15) = "1." & strSearch1 & "  2." & strSearch2 'úå ùàåúå çéôùå
                             Cells(x, 16) = strLine2 'è÷ñè áùåøä ìôðé
                             Mid1 = Mid(Cells(x, 16), Cells(x, 14) - 12, 5)
                             Cells(x, 17) = Cells(x, 16) & " " & Mid1 & Cells(x, 3) & ".pdf"

                                For z = 1 To 10 'áîéãä åéù òåã îàåúä äçáøä åàåúå äúú àæ ëàï äúåñôåú ëøèéñéí ðöáøéí
                                If Cells(x, 7) = Cells(x + z, 7) And Cells(x, 2) = Cells(x + z, 2) Then

                                     Cells(x + z, 16) = Cells(x + h, 17)
                                     Mid2 = Mid(Cells(x + z, 16), Cells(x, 14) - 12, 5)
                                     Cells(x + z, 17) = Cells(x + z, 16) & " " & Mid2 & Cells(x + z, 3) & ".pdf"
                                     h = h + 1
                                End If
                                Next z

                             Exit For



                        End If
                        Next j

                           Open myFileCOMPANY For Output As #i
                            Write #i, "dfgdfg" 'Cells(x + z, 17)

                Exit Do

                Else: Cells(x, 11) = Cells(x, 2)
                      Cells(x, 12) = Cells(x, 7)
                      Cells(x, 15) = "Dfile" & Format(Cells(x, 7), "000") & " not found"

               End If

           Loop

           Close #i

            LineCount1 = 0

            Else: Cells(x, 11) = "No folder number " & Cells(x, 2)

        End If
        x = x + h
        h = 0
        x = x + 1

    Loop


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------äçæøú çéùåáéí åòãëåðé îñê åäúøàåú
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------æîï ñéåí øéöú ÷åã åçéùåá
    Finish = Timer
    TotalTime = Format((Finish - Start) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    MsgBox ("äãå''ç îåëï" & vbNewLine & "æîï øéöú ÷åã: " & TotalTime)


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your code.  Have you looked at the other methods of use of a text file `append`  or do you want to insert at a specific point in the file

Comment: I have 2 excel cells. one with a string and the other cell with a number. I want to take the string and copy it to a txt file in line number I have in the other excel cell

Comment: Dan, you need to prefix the screen name of the person you want to address with `@` in order to notify them of a response in comments.

Comment: One very important point would be to *remove* the line `On Error Resume Next`. This will be hiding any errors which makes it almost impossible to trouble-shoot problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what code you have tried. It would be easier if you included your code.

You could try using:

```
If Application.Options.Overtype Then
        Application.Options.Overtype = False
    End If
```

If you are trying to add a line to the end of your document you can use the following code:

```
Function WordAddEnd()
   Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, objSelection As Object
   Dim endpoint As Integer, moveit As Integer
   Dim FileString As String


endpoint = 6
moveit = 0
FileString = "C:\location\folder\document.docx"
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Onerror resumenext   
'change error handling

Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Open(FileString)

Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

With objSelection
    .EndKey endpoint, moveit
'finds end point of document

    .typeparagraph     
'goes to next line (like pressing the enter key)

    .TypeText ("It's some text you wanted")
'your text here

End With
objWord.documents.Close

End Function
```

If the document in question is already open, there will be an error so you'll need some error handling in here.

Comment: thanks but no. I have 2 excel cells. one with a string and the other cell with a number.
I want to take the string and copy it to a txt file in line number I have in the other excel cell.